# How to print a html-table with a lot of columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing, width

I'm trying to print a table with a lot of columns, so that the width of the table doesn't fit a single page.

I'm using jqprint to print that table. But it prints only the left part of the table, and the right part it won't print.
Is there a way to print the table on multiple pages?

Kind regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would calculate the size per column you need, and when you see it wont fit your paper anymore, put it from that column in a new table. and so on... till you did the whole table.
And put some page-breaks after eacht table.

Comment: How do you break on a td what css or html code do you use?

Answer (score 2):

using CSS you can specify page breaks.

Look here at [www.w3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_reference.asp) for reference
Look here at [javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml) for a tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i didn't knew about these page breaks. But it seems to be you can't break a table in "multiple" tables after columns. (or i just can't manage it :-) ) I think i will go break my table in multiple tables, and with those page breaks, i can set them on the different pages.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the data out of the table. think of a tr as a ol and each td as a li.
lists will print pretty on landscape or portrait and you could put a pagebreak before each ol.

pagebreaks don't work/allowed within a table.

Comment: @Darren do you have a code sample?